# Trying to generate Fibonacci series using recursive WITH clause, getting error: 'cycle detected while executing'

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

I am trying to generate Fibonacci series using below query (recursive WITH clause).

```
WITH X(Pnbr,Cnbr) AS
(SELECT 0, 1 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT X.Cnbr, X.Pnbr+X.Cnbr FROM X
 WHERE X.Cnbr<50
)
 SELECT * FROM X
```

But I am getting this error

```
ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data at first iteration would be

```
PNBR  CNBR
0   , 1
1   , 1 + 0
```

So, CNBR is 1 is first two rows.. A Cycle is detected!

The `CONNECTING` condition has to be **unique**!

> So probably you would need to maintain an iterator.

`ROWNUM` is what I used here for it.

```
WITH X(iter,Pnbr,Cnbr) AS
(SELECT 1,0, 1 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT iter + rownum, X.Cnbr, X.Pnbr+X.Cnbr FROM X
 WHERE iter < 50
)
 SELECT iter,Pnbr FROM X;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/512)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the diagnosis in M. Ravisankar's Answer (from 2015), but not with the remedy.

To handle precisely the situation presented in the original post, recursive CTE offers the `CYCLE` clause. In this problem, while there will be repeated values in the `Pnbr` column as well as in the `Cnbr` column, when considered separately, there are no repeated values (duplicates) in the **composite** `(Pnbr, Cnbr)`.

So, the query can be written like this:

```
WITH X(Pnbr,Cnbr) AS
(SELECT 0, 1 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT X.Cnbr, X.Pnbr+X.Cnbr FROM X
 WHERE X.Cnbr<50
)
cycle Pnbr, Cnbr set cycle to 'Y' default 'N'    ----
SELECT Pnbr, Cnbr FROM X
```

Notice the `cycle` clause (second to last line), and also `SELECT Pnbr, Cnbr` as opposed to `SELECT *` (if we selected * here, we would also get the `cycle` column, which we don't need).

Answer (score 0):

modify the column in the where clause. Use `X.Pnbr+X.Cnbr` instead of `X.Cnbr` as the condition so that Oracle uses the two referenced columns for the row cycling detection.

```sql
WITH X(Pnbr,Cnbr) AS
(SELECT 0, 1 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT X.Cnbr, X.Pnbr+X.Cnbr FROM X
 -- Cnbr column is used to detect the cycle data
 WHERE X.Pnbr+X.Cnbr < 50
)
 SELECT * FROM X;
```

According to the [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BABFFJFD):

> If you omit the CYCLE clause, then the recursive WITH clause returns an error if cycles are discovered. In this case, a row forms a cycle if one of its ancestor rows has the same values for all the columns in the column alias list for query_name that are referenced in the WHERE clause of the recursive member.

Query Outputs:

[image: Executing Result]